# I tried to combine both interpolation and binary search. How can I mathematically prove it will work all the time?

Tags: arrays, c, search, binary-search

The objective is to determine whether a specific value is present within a sorted array that is arranged in ascending order. If the value is found, the search should return a boolean value of true along with the index at which the value is located. If the value is not found, the search should return the index at which the value would be appropriately inserted. This approach was developed through a process of trial and error. How can one prove the soundness of the logic of the code below?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

static inline double interpolate(int value, size_t left, size_t right, int *data) {
    double result = (double)(left) + (((double)(right - left)) * (((double)value) - ((double)data[left])) / ((double)(data[right] - data[left])));
    return result;
}

static inline void update_ib_search_bounds(int value, size_t *interpolation, size_t *left, size_t *right, size_t *mid, int *array) {
    if(value > array[*interpolation]) {
        (*interpolation)++;
        if(value <= array[*interpolation]) {
            *left = *right = *interpolation;
            return;
        }
        *mid = (*interpolation + *right) / 2;
        *left = (value <= array[*mid]) ? ((*right = *mid), (*interpolation + 1)) : (*mid + 1);
    } else {
        size_t lookIdx = *interpolation - 1;
        if(*interpolation == *left || value > array[lookIdx]) {
            *left = *right = *interpolation;
            return;
        }
        *mid = (*interpolation + *left) / 2;
        *right = (value >= array[*mid]) ? ((*left = *mid), lookIdx) : (*mid - 1);
    }
}

bool ibs_isValInArray(int value, int *data, size_t left, size_t data_len, size_t *idx) { 
    /**
     * Assumptions : 
     * 1) data is sorted in ascending order and all the values in data are unique
     * 2) left >=0 and right <= data.size - 1
     * */ 
    if(data_len == 0 || value < data[left]) {
        *idx = left;
        return false;
    }
    size_t mid, right = data_len - 1;
    if(value > data[right]) {
        *idx = data_len;
        return false;
    }
    size_t lp_cnt = 0;
    while(left < right) {
        *idx = (size_t)interpolate(value, left, right, data);
        update_ib_search_bounds(value, idx, &left, &right, &mid, data);
        lp_cnt++;
    }
    printf("lpcnt: %zu\n",lp_cnt);
    return (value == data[left]);
}


int main(void) {
    int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55};
    int array2[] = {1,10,15,30,400,401,402,600,620,640,650,700,701,702,705,2000,2005,3000,3200,3400,3500,3600,6000,6200,6500,6700,6800,6801,6803,8000,9001,9010,9100,9300,9500,9601,9602,9802,9900};
    int array3[] = {343, 1540, 1562, 2135, 2275, 2559, 3780, 4440, 4946, 6110, 6200, 7040, 7290, 7541, 7881, 9269};
    printf(
        "Arrays available:\n"
        "1)array1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55}\n"
        "2)array2[] = {1,10,15,30,400,401,402,600,620,640,650,700,701,702,705,2000,2005,3000,3200,3400,3500,3600,6000,6200,6500,6700,6800,6801,6803,8000,9001,9010,9100,9300,9500,9601,9602,9802,9900}\n"
        "3)array3[] = {343, 1540, 1562, 2135, 2275, 2559, 3780, 4440, 4946, 6110, 6200, 7040, 7290, 7541, 7881, 9269};\n"
    );
    int number;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    size_t array1_len = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]);
    size_t array2_len = sizeof(array2) / sizeof(array2[0]);
    size_t array3_len = sizeof(array3) / sizeof(array3[0]);
    size_t idx;
    // ibsearch
    while(1) {
        printf("Enter array number:");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        int *p;
        size_t len;
        switch (number)
        {
        case 1:
            p = array1;
            len = array1_len;
            break;
        case 2:
            p = array2;
            len = array2_len;
            break;
        case 3:
            p = array3;
            len = array3_len;
            break;
        default:
            p = NULL;
            len = 0;
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter a key to find in array %d: ", number);
        scanf("%d", &number);
        printf("You entered: %d\n", number);

        start = clock();
        if(ibs_isValInArray(number, p, 0, len, &idx)) {
            printf("Found at idx: ");
        } else {
            printf("Not found. idx is at :");
        }
        printf("%zu\n", idx);
        end = clock();
        cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Time taken for IBS in array: %f seconds\n", cpu_time_used);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On a quick review, I do not that `(*interpolation)++`  is prevented to not exceed `right`, which leads to bad things.  Will need to review more later.

Comment: I think `interpolation` does not exceed right because of the check `value > data[right]` in `ibs_isValInArray` function. What can happen? but if u find it to be the case let me know please.

Comment: You might want to consider presenting this over on [codereview.se] when it's complete to your satisfaction.  There's certainly some improvements that can be made to correctness, readability and test coverage.

Comment: I think you are right. that forum is more appropriate. Can you comment on any improvement that can made specifically? @TobySpeight

Comment: Not gonna do it for you, but it does not matter what method you use to select the next “mid” point (whether by linear interpolation or whatever) — as long as your new “mid” point does not violate your next subsection bounds before the search is complete (and it does so in a way that will actually terminate the search), then it is good. Make sure to profile whether fancy interpolation makes a significant improvement. (I don’t imagine it does for anything less than a fairly massive dataset.)

Comment: Just one example: `*mid = (*interpolation + *right) / 2` is a risky way to calculate midpoint, since `+` can overflow.  Prefer `*interpolation + (*right - interpolation) / 2`.  There's other issues that a good review will uncover.

Comment: Looks needlessly complicated to me. The basic search algorithm is `while (left < right) { size_t m = guess(left, right, data); update_bounds(left, right, data, m);` If you want your guess to be computed by a first_order interpolation, by a bisection (aka a zeroth order interpolation), or by anything else, it doesn't matter, the framework stays the same, as long as `m` is between `left` and `right`. So you want to combine bisection and interpolation, calling one or the other every other time. Doesn't matter, the framework is still the same.

Comment: Thank you for your comments everyone. Thank you Toby for the example and Thank you  n. m. could be an AI for the clarification.

Comment: OT: I would do `end = clock();` before doing `printf`